# eclipse Maven 401 Unauthorized when "Allow Anonymous Access" is enabled in Artifactory

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, artifactory

When global anonymous access is disabled in the security settings deployment works fine, but with anonymous access enabled I get the 401 exception and only the POM file gets uploaded to the repository (MojoFailureException in eclipse).

If I enabled "Force Maven Authentication" for a selected repository it also works, but then users need to login to download releases which isn't what I want.

The problem popped up after a re-install of eclipse.

So why I am running into an exception if I don't require a authentication, but supply the informations?

I am running on Artifactory 7.

Comment: Are you getting the same error when trying to download anonymously with another client, for example curl? Did you validate that eclipse is indeed sending an anonymous request? take a look at the Artifactory request log to see if the request was authenticated

Comment: To which log are you referring exactly? Because both the access-request & artifactory-request log don't get updated when trying to deploy neither do they contain any informations. A interesting thing is that the POM file gets deployed successful only the jar files fail.

Comment: Do you see any other requests in the request logs (access, artifactory)? do you see the requests to deploy the .pom file?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay I swapped to Artifactory 6 for testing (still the same issues). eclipse indeed sends a anonymous request to put the jar and pom file (request.log) which get denied for client "NA" (access.log). Afterwards a request is send from eclipse with my user, but only for the POM which then also gets accepted.